# Properly closing a form running a loop in a new thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, formclosing

I have method in my form that is running a do while loop in a new thread.

That for loop exits once a sentinel value is set to true (set by another method that handles `Me.FormClosing`)

The issue is that when the form closes, I get occasionally get two exceptions.

`ObjectDisposedException` and `ComponentModel.Win32Exception`.

How do I properly exit a form without "eating" these exceptions and ignoring them.

Code:

```
Dim _exit As Boolean

Public Sub test()
    Dim task As Thread = New Thread(
            Sub()
                Do
                    checkInvoke(Sub() a.append("a"))
                Loop While _exit = False
            End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub checkInvoke(ByVal _call As Action)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() checkInvoke(_call))
    Else
        _call.Invoke()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    _exit = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know that value has changed? How about some code.

Comment: Added a mock-up of my code.

Comment: If _exit is false, then you have to cancel the closing of the form with `e.Handled = true`

Comment: `Handled` is not a member of `FormClosingEventArgs`

Comment: Cancel, not Handled, sorry.

Comment: I think we're a bit confused, when the form is exited, `Form1_FormClosing` is called, and the form exiting is handled, setting _exit to true.

After _exit is set to true, the loop in `test()` terminates because the loop condition is not true anymore therefore closing the thread. The issue is that I'm getting the exceptions mentioned above by closing the form this way.

Comment: You have to do it the other way around.  If the user is trying to close the form and your loop is running, you have to cancel the closing of the form until your loop is closed up, then you can close the form.  It probably requires another variable like "closePending" and if true, then you call `Me.Close` after your loop code.

Comment: What I thought to do was to put, `checkInvoke(Sub() Me.Close())` after the loop terminates when `_exit is true`. The issue is that because `e.canceled = true`, the form doesn't close...

Comment: You only set Canceled to true if your loop is still looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where does the error come from ?**

This can be a bit confusing but it actually is pretty logical...

1. The user (or something else) closes the form.
2. `FormClosing` is then called which sets `_exit` to `True`
3. Then the Form closes itself, destroying its handle.
4. Now, it depends where it sometimes throws an exception :

   - Either the Thread just finished the Invoke or the Loop, check the `_exit` value then ends the loop, everything goes fine.
   - Either it just began the Invoke, then it calls a method invoking the UI thread to modify something on the form that has just been disposed, no more Handle to this form, leading to `ObjectDisposedException`

**How to prevent this ?**

One thing you can do is, in your `FormClosing` event, wait for the Thread to end, then letting the system close the form :

```
Private _isFinished As Boolean = False
Private _exit As Boolean = False

Public Sub test()
    Dim task As Thread = New Thread(
            Sub()
                Do
                    checkInvoke(Sub() a.append("a"))
                Loop While _exit = False
                'We inform the UI thread we are done
                _isFinished = True
            End Sub)
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    _exit = True
    While Not _isFinished
        Application.DoEvent() 'We can't block the UI thread as it will be invoked by our second thread...
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I understood where the issue came from, it's a bit like russian roulette -- hoping you exited the program at the right moment. What I didn't understand was how to fix the issue. After looking up what DoEvent does, it makes sense now. DoEvent waits till the form that it's called on is complete.

Comment: More or less. DoEvent actually looks if there is any messages for the form (mouse click, keyboard stroke or invoke calls) and then process them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar to VB, but I have done a similar thing in c++. The main problem is that the for loop does not finish yet when the form is closing. You can just hide the form, wait for the thread to finish and then close the form. You can use flags tomark the stopping of the paralel thread.